# Change the background color using selectable jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use sortable and selectable jQuery to moving item between tables. The moving item work as expected. However, I would like to have a difference background color when the item selected, but it didn't work. Would someone indicate a solution to me? Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  // Make the list selectable
  $('.ulClass').selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected");
    },
    unselected: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.unselected).removeClass("ui-selected");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-state-default {
  background-color: white;
}

.ui-selected {
  background: #F39814 !important;
  color: white;
}

.ui-selecting {
  background: blue;
}

.ui-selected.ui-selecting {
  background: #F39814 !important;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<span>
   <ul id="div_3" class="clsDiv ulClass ui-sortable ui-selectable">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle ui-selectee" name="92">Ben</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle ui-selectee" name="108">Owen</li>
   </ul>
</span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Does the demo above reflect your situation? Please update as needed. Note that your styles work fine until the jQueryUI theme is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You must use more specific Styling to address the issue. Please see example.

```js
$(function() {
  // Make the list selectable
  $('.ulClass').selectable();
});
```

```css
.ui-state-default {
  background-color: white;
}

ul.ui-selectable li.ui-selected {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}

li.ui-selecting {
  background: blue;
}

ul.ui-selectable li.ui-selected.ui-selecting {
  background: #F39814;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" integrity="sha512-ELV+xyi8IhEApPS/pSj66+Jiw+sOT1Mqkzlh8ExXihe4zfqbWkxPRi8wptXIO9g73FSlhmquFlUOuMSoXz5IRw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<span>
   <ul id="div_3" class="clsDiv ulClass ui-sortable ui-selectable">
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" name="92">Ben</li>
     <li class="ui-state-default ui-sortable-handle" name="108">Owen</li>
   </ul>
</span>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha512-57oZ/vW8ANMjR/KQ6Be9v/+/h6bq9/l3f0Oc7vn6qMqyhvPd1cvKBRWWpzu0QoneImqr2SkmO4MSqU+RpHom3Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: yes I found the mistake on Styling. By the way, would you  tell me how to create run code snippet as you did.

Comment: @user819774 please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do